# Getting field value that attached to Commerce product field

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

From using commerce_price_savings_formatter, I've created field `field_diskon` where it only contains number. `field_diskon` purpose is for discount rate.

So, I can assign different discount rate for different SKU.

For getting value in `field_specific_blabla` attached to node, I can use:

```
// Extract the first field item
$specific_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_specific_blabla');
$specific_item = array_shift($specific_items);

// Get the field value
$itemvalue = $specific_item['value'];
```

But how to get value `field_diskon` attached to commerce product field?

I have no idea what entity hold commerce field. I've tried replacing `node` with keyword related to commerce, but still not works.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [`entity_metadata_wrapper`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!includes!entity.wrapper.inc/class/EntityMetadataWrapper/7) quite nicely for this. Note that it is part of the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity), but that is a dependency of Drupal Commerce so you'll be fine in this case.

Something like the following code should do it:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', YOUR-REQUIRED-PRODUCT-ID);

$discount = $wrapper->field_diskon->value();
```

You can find out more about how to use `entity_metadata_wrapper()` [here](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/how-use-entity-metadata-wrappers-drupal-7).

Answer (score 0):

commerce_price_savings_formatter only handles the display of the price with discount, it doesn't provide a method for creating the discounted price (AFAIK). If you want a field that allows a sale price to be set per-product then you can use [Commerce Sale Price](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_saleprice). If you want to have a rule that applies to all products check out [this page on product pricing rules](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/461).